# Bound on the integral of a differentiable function against sine functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inequality, fourier-series

Consider a function $f: [0, L] \to \Bbb R$ and $k$ natural number. Suppose that $f', f'', ...$ $f^{n-1}$ are continuous and that $f^{k}$ is absolutely integrable. Show

$$
\left|
\int_{0}^{L}{f(x)\sin \left(\frac{nx\pi}{L}\right) dx}\right| \leq \dfrac{C}{n^{k}}$$

$n=1,2,3...$, where $C$ is a positive constant.

#### Progress

I tried integration by parts: 
$$\int_{0}^{L}{f(x)\sin\left(\dfrac{nx\pi}{L}\right)dx} =  
\dfrac{-L}{n\pi}(\cos(n\pi)f(L)-f(0))+\dots $$ 
And $n^{k}$ is obtained, but my question is whether this well bounded so, because it could continue to take many $n$'s of the integral.

Comment: Have you tried doing integration by parts?

Comment: Oh yeah that's what I did, $\int_{}^{}{f(x)sin(\dfrac{nx\pi}{L})dx}= \dfrac{-L}{n\pi}(cos(n\pi)f(L)-f(0))+...$ And n ^ {k} is obtained, but my question is whether this well bounded so, because it could continue to take many n's of the integral

Comment: @pablocn_ Dont you fix $n$ before getting the bound?

Comment: See [Intuition behind decay of Fourier coefficients](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93066/intuition-behind-decay-of-fourier-coefficients) and [Differentiability and decay of magnitude of fourier series coefficients](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28443/differentiability-and-decay-of-magnitude-of-fourier-series-coefficients)